# How to turn off EBean enhancement

Tags: java, database, jpa, ebean

I have been using Ebean with enhancement for a while. It works most of the time but it's very brittle and really cumbersome to get the configuration right. I hope turning it off could improve the robustness.

My issue is that if I turn off the enhancer in Eclipse and Maven, I start to get various exceptions. What steps should I follow to get rid of the enhancement?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the line ebean.default="models.*" from your application.conf. It worked for me.

Comment: He is not talking about Ebean + Play Framework, so no "application.conf" for him.

Answer (score 0):

This is now an old question from the time that Ebean supported both enhancement and "dynamic subclass generation".

With Ebean we dropped support for "dynamic subclass generation" a few years ago and that is no longer an option (for a number of reasons) so note that **Ebean now mandates enhancement**.

There has been a lot of effort go into the enhancement tooling, especially the IntelliJ IDEA enhancer plugin to make it robust (work to support Kotlin partial compiles comes to mind for example).

If there are people having issues with enhancement please let us (the Ebean project) know, thanks.